# Display date without time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, date, razor

How display date without time? (In database I have without time, just data).

I get on a site:

2012-02-05 00:00:00

2012-02-07 00:00:00

2012-02-08 00:00:00

2012-11-30 00:00:00

Controller:

```
           var today = DateTime.Now.Date;

            var date = (from d in baza.Rezerwacjas 
                        where today<= d.data_rezerwacji 
                        select new { d.data_rezerwacji }).Distinct();

            ViewBag.daty = date;

            return View();
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

        @{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.daty ,null, "Daty", 8);
              }
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
               grid.Column("data_rezerwacji","Daty")           


      )
        )


    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String datestring = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", daty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a .ToString method with Formats like 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Comment: `mm` in lower case means minutes.

Comment: I made:
`ViewBag.daty = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`
And I have a error:
`No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: Cause date is a collection not a simple variable, make it like this date.ToList().Select(o=> o.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); and if you care ToList() was called cause I'm not sure if .ToString() can beexecuted in LinqToSql.

Answer (score 0):

constroller:

```
DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

View:
    model.Returndate = DateTime.Now.Date;

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Returndate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```